# Why doesn't .includes() find subarrays? (javascript)

Tags: javascript

`[0, 1].includes(1)          //returns true`
but
`[[0], [1]].includes([1])    //returns false`

Why is this?
(This is my first post, please be nice)

Comment: Separate arrays won't be `===` to each other. Hopefully we'll eventually be able to use [`.equals`](https://stackoverflow.com/a/63590182), but until then, you'll have to iterate through each element.

Comment: Use `console.log([0, 1]) ` and `console.log([[0], [1]]) ` in your browser, hint: indexes. ︀